# how to find min and max in an array MIPS

Tags: mips

i can find the max perfectly fine but when it comes to finding the min, im having some trouble, my max finds the max number good but my min always prints out 0 no matter what, i cant seem to find out what is wrong with my code, does anyone see the flaw in my code?

For exmaple:

i enter in 5 integers

5 10 15 20 25

Array: 5,10,15,20,25

Min: 0
Max: 25

```
.text
    .globl main

main:
    la $a0, ask             #ask user for integer thats going to be the size of the array
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 5               #store that int
    syscall
    move $t1,$v0            #size of my array stored in $t1

    la $t0, array           #load address of our array
    li $t2, 0               #counter = 0
    lw $t3,($t0)            #initialize min = array[0]
    lw $t4,($t0)            #initialize max = array[0]


while:
    la $a0, intask          #ask user for integer
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 5               #store that int
    syscall
    sw $v0, ($t0)           #store that int in the array


end:    add $t0, $t0, 4         #increment the array to the next index
    add $t2, $t2, 1         #increment the counter by 1
    blt $t2, $t1,while      #branch to while if counter < size of array

endw:
    la $a0,display          # Display "Array is: "
    li $v0,4            
    syscall

    li $t0, 0               # initilize array index value back to 0
    li $t2, 0                # initial size counter back to zero
    la $t0, array            # load address of array back into $t0

 sprint:
    lw $t6,($t0)            #load word into temp $t2
    move $a0, $t6           #store it to a safer place
    li $v0, 1               #print it out
    syscall

    la $a0,space            # Display " "
    li $v0,4            
    syscall

    add $t0, $t0, 4         #increment the array to the next index
    add $t2, $t2, 1         #increment the counter by 1

    blt $t2, $t1,sprint     #branch to while if counter < size of array

    li $t2, 0                # initial size counter back to zero
    la $t0, array            # load address of array back into $t0
    add $t0, $t0, 4         #increment the array to the next index
    add $t2, $t2, 1         #increment the counter by 1


 loop:  lw $t8,($t0)             # t8 = next element in array
    bge $t8, $t3, notMin     #if array element is >= min goto notMin
    move $t3,$t8             #min = array[i]
    j notMax

 notMin: ble $t8,$t4, notMax         #if array element is <= max goto notMax
    move $t4,$t8             #max = array[i]

 notMax:    add $t2,$t2,1            #incr counter
    add $t0,$t0, 4           #go up in index
    blt $t2, $t1,loop        #if counter < size, go to loop

 eprint:
    la $a0,nextline          # Display "\n"
    li $v0,4            
    syscall

    la $a0,min               # Display "min number is "
    li $v0,4            
    syscall

    move $a0, $t3            #displays min number in array
    li $v0,1
    syscall

    la $a0,nextline          # Display "\n"
    li $v0,4            
    syscall

    la $a0,max               # Display "max number is "
    li $v0,4            
    syscall

    move $a0, $t4            #displays max number in array
    li $v0,1
    syscall

    li $v0,10                # End Of Program
    syscall     

.data
array: .space 100
ask: .asciiz "How many numbers will be entered? no more than 15 numbers!: "
intask: .asciiz "Enter an Integer: "
min: .asciiz "The minimum number is: "
max: .asciiz "The maximum number is: "
display: .asciiz "Array: "
space: .asciiz " "
nextline: .asciiz "\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `$t3` (which is used for storing min) to `array[0]` before any values are stored in `array`, so `$t3` ends up being initialized to 0.

It should be fine if you initialize `$t3` to `array[0]` *after* values have been entered into `array`.